# How does turtle geometry keep track of which way is up/down?

Tags: rotations

I'm having an issue understanding how turtle geometry is supposed to work.

[image: Turtle geometry is a simple way of drawing lines to create shapes in 3d space. Wherever the turtle walks to you are able to draw a line based on the commands that are given to it] [image]

Let's say for the orientation vector *O* the Heading, Left, and Up unit vectors for the turtle are:

[image]

So the turtle is facing entirely in the x-direction.

If you wanted to rotate the turtle by some angle about the x-axis, such that the belly of the turtle would be rotating, you would take the RH matrix:

[image]

and multiply it by the orientation vector *O* like so:

[image]

So, clearly the turtle's orientation stays the same since it is facing directly on the x-axis. No rotation occurs. How is the "belly" of the turtle supposed to be rotated if you wanted to turn him upside down?

Comment: You wouldn't multiply the $[H L U]$ vector with a rotation matrix.  In practice you would convert the  $[H L U]$ vector into a rotation matrix.  Rotation matrices transform vectors from one coordinate system to the other.  $[H L U]$ is not a vector in the normal sensse.